# Decision variable (or expression) "x" not allowed error in cplex

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, opl

I am building a CPLEX OPL model. I found error: Decision variable (or expression) "x" not allowed.

Here x is a decision variable and shown below:

```
dvar boolean x[N][CR];
Constraint:
forall(i in N, j in CR :x[i][j]==1) {


(j%2 == 0) => r[i] == 1;




(j%2 == 1) => r[i] == 0; 




}
```

How I write this constraint correctly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
range N=1..2;
range CR=1..3;

dvar boolean x[N][CR];
dvar boolean r[N];
subject to
{
forall(i in N, j in CR ) {


((j%2 == 0) && (x[i][j]==1)) => (r[i] == 1);




((j%2 == 1) && (x[i][j]==1)) => (r[i] == 0); 




}
}
```

works fine

Comment: Thank you for the response.Syntactically it is correct but not providing the correct answer.